# R: Highlight cells in the cor() table that have a correlation coefficient greater than a threshold

Tags: r, correlation

The cor() function R, when called on a dataframe, returns a matrix containing the correlation coefficients associated with pairwise elements fro the dataframe. But there doesn't seem to be any option to mark the coefficients that have values above some threshold (like STATA's *)

Is there any indirect way to get R to do this?

For example,

```
M = matrix(rnorm(20*5, mean = 10, sd = 3), 20, 5)
symnum(cor(M), cutpoints =  c(0.1, 0.5),
    symbols = c( '', '*', '**'),
    legend = TRUE,
     corr = TRUE)
```

returns a matrix devoid of the correlation coefficients; '', '*' or '**' have replaced the values. I'd like to generate a table that contains the correlation coefficients, and at the same time display a '*' in the cell if the coefficient value is greater than 0.1, and display '**' if the coefficient value is greater than 0.5

Comment: Have you read `?symnum`? Could you define exactly what your desired output should be?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

One option might be the `corrplot` package.

```
corrplot(cor(M), method='number')
```

[image: Corrplot]

Answer (score 1):

`symnum` returns a matrix of same dimensions as the correlation matrix, `co` in this example. This piece of code does 3 things, calculate the correlation matrix and rounds it of to 2 digits. Then uses `paste` to concatenate the numbers and the significance returned from `symnum`. Just one issue: `paste` reduces the matrix to a vector, so we have to re-setup the matrix form. Luckily, both matrix and paste uses column-order, i.e. the elements are ordered per column.

```
co <- cor(M)
co <- round(co, 2)
co[upper.tri(co, diag=TRUE)] <- ''
s <- symnum(co)
noquote(matrix(paste(co, s), ncol=ncol(co)))
attr(s, 'legend')
```